# Radio button css and IE9

Tags: html, css, forms, webforms

Hello i have been trying to use customize radio button and following is my css. I have checked it with two browsers IE9 and Google chrome on google chrome its working fine but on ie9 my mentioned image for radio button is not getting displayed kindly let me know how to fix the following css so it'll work on ie9 too

```
input[type="radio"] {
background:url('images/radio_Checked.jpg');
padding:0;
width:10px;
height:10px;
display: inline-block;
appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
vertical-align:middle;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked  {
background:url('images/radio_Unchecked_Small.jpg');

}
```

**ALso tried the following css it also works fine on google only**

```
input[type="radio"]:checked
{
 -khtml-appearance: none;
 background: url('images/radio_Checked.jpg');
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: `apearance`, `-moz-apearance`, and `-webkit-apearance` any of these did not have `none` option. check out these references: 1. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp , 2. http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/appearance.htm

Comment: i just want to bring a specific background on the checked radio button with the 2nd mentioned css the background appears on IE9 but  with the black dot and on google chrome works fine and black dot doesn't come

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `class` or `id` attribute to your radio buttons and setting a style for them in your CSS file

```
.styled
{

background: url('test.jpg');

}

#styled
{
background: url('test.jpg');
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" class="styled">

<input type="radio" name="radio" id="styled">
```

Comment: i want to put the functionlaity on checked attiribut only kinly let me know how can i do that